# Randomize table rows with JS while displaying one table row at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablerow

I am attempting to create a table that will only display one row at a time and also randomize on each refresh. Here is my code:

```
<script>
var maxRows = 1; //displays one row at a time
$('#song-list').each(function() {
var cTable = $(this);
var cRows = cTable.find('tr:gt(0)');
var cRowCount = cRows.size();

if (cRowCount < maxRows) {
    return;
}

/* hide all rows above the max initially */
cRows.filter(':gt(' + (maxRows - 1) + ')').hide();

var cPrev = cTable.siblings('.prev');
var cNext = cTable.siblings('.next');

/* start with previous disabled */
cPrev.addClass('disabled');

cPrev.click(function() {
    var cFirstVisible = cRows.index(cRows.filter(':visible'));

    if (cPrev.hasClass('disabled')) {
        return false;
    }

    cRows.hide();
    if (cFirstVisible - maxRows - 1 > 0) {
        cRows.filter(':lt(' + cFirstVisible + '):gt(' + (cFirstVisible - maxRows - 1) +     ')').show();
    } else {
        cRows.filter(':lt(' + cFirstVisible + ')').show();
    }

    if (cFirstVisible - maxRows <= 0) {
        cPrev.addClass('disabled');
    }

    cNext.removeClass('disabled');

    return false;
});

cNext.click(function() {
    var cFirstVisible = cRows.index(cRows.filter(':visible'));

    if (cNext.hasClass('disabled')) {
        return false;
    }

    cRows.hide();
    cRows.filter(':lt(' + (cFirstVisible +2 * maxRows) + '):gt(' + (cFirstVisible +       maxRows - 1) + ')').show();

    if (cFirstVisible + 2 * maxRows >= cRows.size()) {
        cNext.addClass('disabled');
    }

    cPrev.removeClass('disabled');

    return false;
});
});
</script>
```

**Second piece of code:**

```
<script>
Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
// Random item in this array.
var r = parseInt(Math.random() * this.length);
var obj = this[r];

// Swap.
this[r] = this[i];
this[i] = obj;
}
}

function randomize(tableID) {
var myTable = document.getElementById(tableID);
var myRows = new Array();
for (i=myTable.rows.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    var theRow = myTable.rows[i];
    myRows.push(theRow);
    theRow.parentNode.removeChild(theRow);
}
myRows.shuffle();
for (j=0; j<myRows.length; j++) {
    myTable.appendChild(myRows[j]);
}
}
window.onload = function() {
randomize("song-list");
}
//-->
</script>
```

Both pieces work fine on their own but when I try to combine them the randomize function supersedes the other code and I get a long list of tr that randomize after refresh.

I know there is something I can do to make these codes agree with one another.

Have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the whole 1st block of code into a function:

```
function showOneRow() {
    ...
}
```

and call it after randomize:

```
window.onload = function() {
    randomize("song-list");
    showOneRow();
}
```

Comment: @flow that worked perfectly!! thank you for the quick response. However, now the table is displaying two rows instead of one? here is the link to my site: http://nostaljams.com/beta.html any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: IMHO: var cRows = cTable.find('tr:gt(0)'); instead of this you should add here all the tr-s: var cRows = cTable.find('tr');

Comment: YES!! Wow. I'm new to coding and it amazes me when people completely understand what they are doing and know how to leverage this knowledge. Thank you for responding so quickly and with brilliant answers to my questions.